# How to include HTML in button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a button group using bootstrap and currently there is a caret displayed next to All:

```
<div class = "input-group-btn">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style = "padding-bottom: 11px;">All <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">All </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Only Played </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Include Free </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Include Free and Only Played </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However when a user clicks on one of the options I want the button to change it's value, so I use the following JQuery:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
});
```

But the caret is then removed. Could somebody explain how to do this but keeping the caret next to the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html()` instead of `text()`, and include the code for the span element when you replace all the content.

Alternatively, wrap the text in another span element, select `$(".btn:first-child span:first-child")` and replace the text of the span.

Alternatively, get rid of the span for the caret and generate a pseudo-element with `:after` to style instead.

Comment: I've changed it to:
( $(this).text() ).concat('<span class="caret"></span>').html()
but this gives me an Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function.

Comment: It was the first text that needed changing not the second, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn:first-child").append($("<span class='carat'/>"))
```

^ Add that to the end of your JS.